# ASP.NET: how to stop page from jumping when using AutoPostBack?

Tags: asp.net, wizard, autopostback, page-jump, maintainscrollpositionon

I'm using ASP.NET, and in a Wizard control I have radio buttons where if "Yes" is selected, a panel is shown, but if "No" is selected, the panel is hidden.  I have MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack set to True, though the ActiveStepChanged event changes it to False so that when you click Next to see the next Wizard step, it will start at the top of the page.  The problem is, after clicking Next, the first time you click on a radio button it jumps to the top of the page (the page retains its position any time you click a radio button after the first time).  How do I stop it from jumping the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the page from doing a full refresh by putting your control in an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx)

Comment: it should also be noted that to use an asp update panel you need an asp script manager. only one script manager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) is allowed per page. it will handle all the requests.

Comment: @mattimus: Good point. To go along with that (the fact that only one script manager can be on a page), make sure you don't put a ScriptManager in a user control; put it on a page (because you might want more than one UC on a page).

Answer (score 6):

Set `Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true` to maintain the current screen position on Postback.

This is easier than trying to do this yourself through JavaScript or whatever means.

Comment: it really helps me today. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but I am unable to use ajax for the project I was working on I was having a similar issue and I found an acceptable work-around. I have a user control within a page that also has a master page.  In the user control there is an input form that has a few controls near the bottom that trigger postback. The main content div on the master page makes this for scrollable (because it is too large). The solution that I found to it was setting the page focus to a control on the events triggered by postback in the c# code-behind. 
For example:

```
protected void cbShip_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    if (cbShip.Checked)
    {
        pnlShip.Visible = true;
        Page.SetFocus(ddlShipCountry);
    }
    else
    {
        pnlShip.Visible = false;
    }
    return;
}
```